# Usage of 'is it possible for a person like me to participate ..' in business letters

Tags: phrases

Does phrase 'Is it possible for a person **like me** to participate in ..' suit for a business letter? How can I rephrase it (without 'like me')?

Thank you!

Comment: Presumably it would depend very much on what you understand *a person like me* to mean. And particularly whether whoever you're writing to also knows *exactly* what you're like, and which specific attribute of yours might be problematic enough for you to ask such a question. If he *doesn't*, the question is almost meaningless. But if he does, why call attention to your own condition? Just ask *Is it possible for a person with two heads to participate in a [head transplant program?*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_transplant) (He'll know *that* if he knows you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing about yourself? In which case just ask "Is it possible for **me** to participate in...".

If you are genuinely writing about some hypothetical other person who resembles you in some way, you could say "such as I" though that might come across as overly formal. But it would probably be much clearer to identify what characteristic about yourself makes you unsure whether you can participate, i.e. "Is it possible for a person who refers to themselves cryptically in the third person to participate in..."